# Why do my files go to the bottom of Solution Explorer with a changed name?

Tags: visual-studio, solution

This is something that happens to me quite often. I click on a `*.fs` file (I am programming in `F#`) in `Solution Explorer`. Then the file disappears from the list and another file appears at the bottom of the list. If the original file name was `Abc.fs` then the new file's name is `Copy of Abc.fs`.

Unfortunately this is not easy to reproduce. I tried:

1) Created a new file `Test.fs` in the `MySolution\MySolution` folder.

2) Added the file to my project as an existing item (not as a link).

3) Moved the file from the bottom of the `Solution Explorer` list to somewhere inside the list.

4) Clicked or double-clicked on the file. It just opened.

5) Kept trying until finally it happened, `Test.fs` disappeared from the `Solution Explorer` list and `Copy of Test.fs` appeared at the bottom of the list.

6) The two files have the same content but `Test.fs` was deleted from the `MySolution\MySolution` folder.

I suspect that the problem occurs when I click rapidly on the file and on another file in `Solution Explorer`, but, as mentioned above, the issue is not easy to reproduce. I just did it but I am not sure how I did it.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Ian - I just installed Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.8.0 and the problem occurred after that. But this has going on for quite a while, with different versions. I update as soon as I see the yellow flag.